# Is there any open source Microsoft Project MPP viewer?

Tags: software-recommendation, project-management

We know that `.mpp` file extension is a proprietary file format. But, Is there any open source viewer which work with these kind of files?

Comment: Have you tried [openproj](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openproj/)

Comment: I wonder which of the options can import recent versions of Microsoft Project... tinkering around with few options got me nowhere so far..

Answer (score 24):

Project Libre has superseded OpenProj and claims Project 2010 compatibility.

http://www.projectlibre.org/ is the homepage

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenProj#Fork_-_ProjectLibre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenProj#Fork%5f-_ProjectLibre) gives some history on how OpenProj forked to give rise to Project Libre.

Comment: Works on linux (checked the rpm version). Versions for MAC and Windows are also available (java, should be cross platform).

Comment: You can download a Debian package for easy installation by surfing to https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/, and then clicking on the version.

Answer (score 4):

Try [MPP Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mppviewer/). It works great.

Comment: MPP Viewer is windows only (.net 4.5 or something like that).

Answer (score 2):

OpenProj does work. You'll be able to print an MPP file to a printer or PDF from there. For unconfidential project files you may also find the online converter sites useful.

Comment: Hi. But OpenProj don't open all versions. There's an other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an open source viewer on the market. But if you need a viewer to open all versions, you can try the [Light](http://www.free-project-viewer.com/) version of [MOOS Project Viewer](http://www.moosprojectviewer.com/). This one is free but limited in functionality. The full version has more features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Project Viewer](https://www.rationalplan.com/on-premise/?downloadfile=http://www.rationalplan.com/download/RationalPlanM-4.0.zip&product=multi&referrer=moos) or [MOOS Project Viewer](http://www.moosprojectviewer.com/download.php).
Both based on Java so it support multi-platform.